# How does WaitOnAddress / WakeByAddressAll / WakeByAddresSingle work

Tags: winapi

Can anyone tell me how WaitOnAddress / WakeByAddressSingle / WakeByAddressAll works internally ? From a MS blog-article I noted that it works with least kernel-intervention.

Comment: I think you want this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160826-00/?p=94185

Comment: That's too vague to me.

Comment: Then you need to decompile the code by yourself. Why do you want to know it exactly? If it is for performance you need to measure anyway.

Comment: That's impossible since there's also some help from the kernel here.
There are common synchronization-primitives like mutex which are well-understood, so there must someone who also undestands how this is realized.

Comment: what concrete you want know ?

Comment: The patent seem to cover this mechanism. It does not have assembly listings, but still has a detailed verbal description: https://patents.google.com/patent/US8782674B2/en direct .pdf link https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/be/9d/1d/28919d92c8a823/US8782674.pdf